# Get the SPHostUrl on additional pages

Tags: sharepoint-addin

This is my first time writing a SharePoint App, and I have hit a bit of a snag. The app has 2 pages. On the first page, I can get the context pretty easily. But on the 2nd page, I don't seem to be able to pull the information. The script will not get past this part:

```
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));
```

Is there any way that I can pull this information? Why wouldn't this data be available from all pages in a sharepoint app?

Is there perhaps a way I can pull this information inside the aspx page, or pass the information from page 1?

Comment: Make sure in the second page url has the SPHostUrl and SPAppWebUrl in  querystring

Comment: How are you navigating from the 1st page to the 2nd page?  Clicking a link, submitting a form, etc.. ?  Is it a SharePoint-hosted app, Provider-hosted app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a query string, all you would have to do is pass it along to the 2nd page in a link or just have the 2nd page be the default page.

Drop this in the first page:

```
<a onclick="javascript:location.href='Page2.aspx' + location.search"> Go to page 1 </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a javascript object called _spPageContextInfo in all sharepoint pages that you can pull using javascript:

```
 _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
```

Use javascript to do that operation for other properties you need that the Javascript context can't give you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj163201.aspx